# MediaWiki API not working using $.getJSON

Tags: javascript, wikipedia, wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api

Here is the link:
https://codepen.io/devanshchawla/pen/XgdrvE?editors=1111

```
var API="https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&prop=info&generator=search&gsrsearch=Albert&callback=?";

$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON(API,function(json){
        console.log(json);
  });
});
```

The output is:

```
Object{
    batchcomplete: "";
    continue: Object{
        continue: "gsroffset||",
        gsroffset: 10
  },
  query: Object{
      pages: Object{}
  }
}
```

I get the expected output when I copy and paste the URL into the browser.

Comment: What's your problem?

Comment: I'm not getting the expected output.

Comment: i can see your expected result in console.log. what's your problem?

Comment: console output in codepen is little misleading. Directly access `json.query.pages` it has expected data